# Is $\mathbb{R}$ connected in the topology generated by $B_{1} = \{[a, b] : a, b ∈ \mathbb{Q}\}$, and $B_{2} = \{[a, b] : a, b ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$

Tags: general-topology

Consider the following collections of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$:

$$B_{1} = \{[a, b] : a, b ∈ \mathbb{Q}\},$$

$$B_{2} = \{[a, b] : a, b ∈ \mathbb{R}\}.$$

Already show that they are two basis and let their topology be $T_1,T_2$.
And $T \subset T_{1} \subset T_{2} $ where $T$ is usual topology.

Asked to determine if $\mathbb{R}$ is connected in $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$.
Have no idea where to start, I think it is clearly connected in these topology but how to actually prove it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something but won't you get that the one-point sets are open in $T_2$?

Answer (score 1):

Topology with a basis $B_1$ is not connected: $\mathbb{R}=(-\infty, 0] \cup (0, +\infty)$ is nontrivial disjoint sum of open sets. For the same reason, topology with a basis $B_2$ is not connected.

To show $(-\infty, 0]$ and $(0, +\infty)$ are open, use the axiom of topological sets, "Arbitrary union of open sets is again open."